# Android listview embedded within scrolling frame

Tags: android, android-listview

I have seen a lot of talk about not putting ListView in ScrollView, but without the ScrollView I cannot see how I can achieve what I want.

I have a Frame that will display subsets of user information. Eg name, age, location, photos... one of the pieces of information is a list of all products the user is subscribed to, which will obviously have a dynamic size depending on how many items. I want this to be a list within the scrollviewer, I dont want the list to separately scroll, just to be initialised to it's full size within the scrollviewer so all scrolling is handled at the parent scrollview level, then you can click on an item in the list to be taken to the sub page for that item.

If I put the ListView outside the ScrollView, I will get two separate indepedently scrolling areas of the screen which I do not want.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you should set the listview height,but you say it's size is dynamic.you can get the view item and then measure the item height,make the listview height fit to total item's height.